# How to bind a property to false value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I would like to bind the IsEnabled property of a ComboBox to the IsChecked property of a checkbox, while I want the ComboBox to be ENABLED only when the checkbox value is FALSE.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=RegexCbx, Path=IsChecked}"
```

What's the simplest way for doing that?

Comment: Well, the easiest way would be `DataTrigger` and the better way would be `ValueConverter`

Comment: simply use a Converter

Answer (score 4):

Use style trigger:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="Foo" Content="Click me"/>
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Foo}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is a simple great solution! Thank you!! I found it helpful while I needed in addition to that, multiple binding... it saved lots of code lines by just adding anothe "DataTrigger" element in addition to the first one! (works with "OR"). Thank you!!!!

Comment: One more question :) Is there any way for doing it for non boolean values. For example that checkbox IsEnable depends on a combobox, but by that simple way using xaml only?

Comment: It's hard to answer without more concrete example, but triggers are rather limited. For complex logic/data types view models or converters are much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

A class derived from IValueConverter should do the trick:

```
public class BoolToOppositeBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Preferably in a Resource Dictionary, create an instance of the converter:

```
<converters:BoolToOppositeBoolConverter x:Key="oppositeBoolConverter" />
```

Then in your view, do something like this where the bool value for IsChecked gets converted to the opposite value.  Don't forget to include the resource dictionary as a resource for the view.

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource oppositeBoolConverter}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that, is to use ***Blend***'s `DataTrigger`:

```
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"

    <ComboBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ie:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RegexCbx}"
                            Value="False">
                <ie:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled"
                                         TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}}"
                                         Value="True"/>
            </ie:DataTrigger>
            <ie:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RegexCbx}"
                            Value="True">
                <ie:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsEnabled"
                                         TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}}"
                                         Value="False"/>
            </ie:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```